# Custom single-header C++ logging library

Tags: c++, performance, c++14, logging

I started learning C++ recently for game development, and decided to write my own little library for debugging.

Here is the library (snoop.hpp)

```cpp
#ifndef SNOOP_HPP
#define SNOOP_HPP

#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <sstream>
#include <functional>

// Enumeration for different log levels
enum class LogLevel {
    FATAL,
    ERROR,
    WARN,
    INFO,
    DEBUG,
    VERB
};

// Forward declaration of Snoop class
class Snoop;

// Type definition for custom error handler function
using ErrorHandler = void (*)(const std::string&);

// Type definition for custom log message formatter function
using LogFormatter = std::function<std::string(LogLevel, const char*, int, const std::string&)>;

class Snoop {
public:
    // Constructor
    Snoop(LogLevel level = LogLevel::INFO, std::string filePath = "", bool log_to_console = true);

    // Destructor
    ~Snoop();

    // Copy Constructor (deleted)
    Snoop(const Snoop&) = delete;

    // Copy Assignment Operator (deleted)
    Snoop& operator=(const Snoop&) = delete;

    // Move Constructor
    Snoop(Snoop&& other);

    // Move Assignment Operator
    Snoop& operator=(Snoop&& other);

    // Method to set a custom error handler
    void SetErrorHandler(ErrorHandler error_handler);

    // Method to set a custom log formatter
    void SetLogFormatter(LogFormatter formatter);

    // Public log methods for different log levels
    void Fatal(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
    void Error(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
    void Warn(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
    void Info(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
    void Debug(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
    void Verb(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);

    // Methods to configure logging behavior
    void LogToFile(std::string filePath);
    void LogToConsole(bool log_to_console);
    void SetLevel(LogLevel level);

private:
    LogLevel level = LogLevel::INFO;
    bool log_to_file = false;
    bool log_to_console = false;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::unique_ptr<std::ofstream> file;
    ErrorHandler error_handler = nullptr;
    LogFormatter log_formatter = nullptr;

    // Helper function for resource transfer
    void swap(Snoop& other) noexcept;

    // Helper function for default message formatting
    std::string formatMessage(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);

    // Internal log function used by public log functions
    void log(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
};

// Macros for simplified logging usage
#define LOG_FATAL(instance, msg) instance.Fatal(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_ERROR(instance, msg) instance.Error(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_WARN(instance, msg)  instance.Warn(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_INFO(instance, msg)  instance.Info(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_DEBUG(instance, msg) instance.Debug(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)
#define LOG_VERB(instance, msg)  instance.Verb(__FILE__, __LINE__, msg)

// Constructor
Snoop::Snoop(LogLevel level, std::string filePath, bool log_to_console) {
    try {
        LogToFile(filePath);
        LogToConsole(log_to_console);
        SetLevel(level);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        // Handle initialization exception
        if (this->error_handler) {
            this->error_handler("Exception during Snoop initialization: " + std::string(e.what()));
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Exception during Snoop initialization: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

// Destructor
Snoop::~Snoop() {
    // unique_ptr will automatically close the file when it goes out of scope
}

// Move Constructor
Snoop::Snoop(Snoop&& other) {
    // Transfer ownership of resources
    swap(other);
}

// Move Assignment Operator
Snoop& Snoop::operator=(Snoop&& other) {
    // Self-assignment check
    if (this != &other) {
        // Release current resources
        if (log_to_file) {
            file.reset(); // Close file by resetting unique_ptr
        }

        // Transfer ownership of resources from 'other' to 'this'
        swap(other);
    }

    return *this;
}

// Helper function to swap resources
void Snoop::swap(Snoop& other) noexcept {
    using std::swap;

    // Ensure thread safety by locking both mutexes
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> otherLock(other.mutex);

    // Transfer resources between 'this' and 'other'
    swap(level, other.level);
    swap(log_to_file, other.log_to_file);
    swap(log_to_console, other.log_to_console);
    swap(file, other.file);
}

// Method to set a custom error handler
void Snoop::SetErrorHandler(ErrorHandler error_handler) {
    this->error_handler = error_handler;
}

// Method to set a custom log formatter
void Snoop::SetLogFormatter(LogFormatter formatter) {
    this->log_formatter = formatter;
}

// Method to set the log level
void Snoop::SetLevel(LogLevel level) {
    this->level = level;
}

// Method to configure logging to console
void Snoop::LogToConsole(bool log_to_console) {
    this->log_to_console = log_to_console;
}

// Method to configure logging to file
void Snoop::LogToFile(std::string filePath) {
    this->file.reset(); // Release previous file handle

    if (!filePath.empty()) {
        try {
            // Attempt to open the specified file for logging
            this->file = std::make_unique<std::ofstream>(filePath, std::ios_base::app);
            if (!(*this->file)) {
                // Error opening file
                if (this->error_handler) {
                    this->error_handler("Failed to open file for logging: " + filePath);
                }
                else {
                    std::cerr << "Error while opening log file: " << filePath << std::endl;
                }
                this->log_to_file = false;
            }
            else {
                // Successfully opened file
                this->log_to_file = true;
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
            // Handle exception while opening the log file
            if (this->error_handler) {
                this->error_handler("Exception while opening log file: " + std::string(e.what()));
            }
            else {
                std::cerr << "Exception while opening log file: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
            this->log_to_file = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Logging to file is disabled
        this->log_to_file = false;
    }
}

// Default message formatting function
std::string Snoop::formatMessage(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    std::ostringstream outstream;

    // Generate timestamp
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    auto now = clock::now();
    auto seconds = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(now);
    auto fraction = now - seconds;
    std::time_t clock_now = clock::to_time_t(now);
    auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(fraction);

    char time_str[20];
    std::strftime(time_str, sizeof(time_str), "%H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&clock_now));

    outstream << time_str;

    // Add log level
    switch(level) {
        case LogLevel::FATAL: outstream << " [FTL] "; break;
        case LogLevel::ERROR: outstream << " [ERR] "; break;
        case LogLevel::WARN:  outstream << " [WRN] "; break;
        case LogLevel::INFO:  outstream << " [INF] "; break;
        case LogLevel::DEBUG: outstream << " [DBG] "; break;
        case LogLevel::VERB:  outstream << " [VRB] "; break;
    }

    outstream << "[" << file << ":" << line << "] ";

    outstream << message;

    return outstream.str();
}

// Internal log function
void Snoop::log(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    // Skip logging if the level is above the set logging level
    if (level > this->level) {
        return;
    }

    std::string outstring;

    // Format the log message using a custom formatter if provided
    if (this->log_formatter) {
        outstring = this->log_formatter(level, file, line, message);
    }
    else {
        // Use the default message formatting function
        outstring = formatMessage(level, file, line, message);
    }

    // Log to console
    if (this->log_to_console) {
        // Lock the mutex for thread safety while logging to console
        this->mutex.lock();
        if (level == LogLevel::FATAL || level == LogLevel::ERROR) {
            std::clog << outstring << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::clog << outstring << "\n";
        }
        this->mutex.unlock();
    }

    // Log to file
    if (this->log_to_file) {
        // Lock the mutex for thread safety while logging to file
        this->mutex.lock();
        if (level == LogLevel::FATAL || level == LogLevel::ERROR) {
            (*this->file) << outstring << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            (*this->file) << outstring << "\n";
        }
        this->mutex.unlock();
    }
}

// Public log functions that call the internal log function
void Snoop::Fatal(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    log(LogLevel::FATAL, file, line, message);
}

void Snoop::Error(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    log(LogLevel::ERROR, file, line, message);
}

void Snoop::Warn(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    log(LogLevel::WARN, file, line, message);
}

void Snoop::Info(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    log(LogLevel::INFO, file, line, message);
}

void Snoop::Debug(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    log(LogLevel::DEBUG, file, line, message);
}

void Snoop::Verb(const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    log(LogLevel::VERB, file, line, message);
}

#endif
```

And here I have a file that showcases how to use it (example.cpp):

```cpp
#include "snoop.hpp"

int main() {
    // Create a Snoop logger instance with INFO level
    Snoop logger(LogLevel::INFO);

    // Set a custom error handler
    logger.SetErrorHandler([](const std::string& error) {
        std::cerr << "Custom Error Handler: " << error << std::endl;
    });

    // Log messages at different levels with the default formatter
    LOG_FATAL(logger, "This is a fatal message.");
    LOG_ERROR(logger, "This is an error message.");
    LOG_WARN(logger, "This is a warning message.");
    LOG_INFO(logger, "This is an info message.");
    LOG_DEBUG(logger, "This is a debug message.");  // Gets skipped
    LOG_VERB(logger, "This is a verbose message."); // Gets skipped

    // Set a custom log formatter
    logger.SetLogFormatter([](LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) -> std::string {
        std::ostringstream formatted;
        formatted << "<" << file << "::" << line << "> ";
        switch (level) {
            case LogLevel::FATAL: formatted << "[FATAL] "; break;
            case LogLevel::ERROR: formatted << "[ERROR] "; break;
            case LogLevel::WARN:  formatted << "[WARN] "; break;
            case LogLevel::INFO:  formatted << "[INFO] "; break;
            case LogLevel::DEBUG: formatted << "[DEBUG] "; break;
            case LogLevel::VERB:  formatted << "[VERB] "; break;
        }
        formatted << message;
        return formatted.str();
    });

    // Change LogLevel to verbose
    logger.SetLevel(LogLevel::VERB);

    // Configure logger to log to a file
    logger.LogToFile("./log/file.log"); // Throws error (directory doesn't exist)

    // Log messages at different levels with the custom formatter
    LOG_FATAL(logger, "This is a fatal message.");
    LOG_ERROR(logger, "This is an error message.");
    LOG_WARN(logger, "This is a warning message.");
    LOG_INFO(logger, "This is an info message.");
    LOG_DEBUG(logger, "This is a debug message.");
    LOG_VERB(logger, "This is a verbose message.");

    // Configure logger to log to a file ONLY 
    logger.LogToFile("./example.log");
    logger.LogToConsole(false);

    // Log additional messages after configuring file logging
    LOG_FATAL(logger, "This is a fatal message (logged to file).");
    LOG_ERROR(logger, "This is an error message (logged to file).");
    LOG_WARN(logger, "This is a warning message (logged to file).");
    LOG_INFO(logger, "This is an info message (logged to file).");
    LOG_DEBUG(logger, "This is a debug message (logged to file).");
    LOG_VERB(logger, "This is a verbose message (logged to file).");

    return 0;
}
```

Anything I could change or add to make my code more safe and/or performant? General C++ advice is welcome too! Thanks :)

Edit: I applied the excellent advice given by G. Sliepen; you can see the updated version here: https://github.com/makeyen/snoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unnecessary things

- You don't need to forward declare `class Snoop`, nothing uses it before you actually define the class.
- `this->` is almost never necessary in C++. The only issue is with `level` in `Snoop::log()`; this can be solved by renaming either the function parameter or the member variable named `level`. I suggest renaming the latter to `maximum_level`.
- The destructor is empty, you can omit its definition entirely.
- Catching errors in the constructor: `error_handler` is never set in the constructor, so it's useless to check for it. It's also better to just let the exception propagate than to print an error message *and then to ignore the error*.
- There is no need to delete the copy constructor and assignment operator explicitly; since the member variable `mutex` is non-copyable, the whole class will be non-copyable by default as well.
- Using a `std::unique_ptr` to hold the `std::ofstream`: you can default-construct a `std::ofstream` that is not associated with any file, and you can `std::move()` and `std::swap()` `std::ofstream`s just like you can with `std::mutex`.

## Simplify the code

There is quite some complexity in `log()` because it can choose between custom formatters or a default one, and can log to a file and/or the console. I would also move the early checks for the log level into the class definition so it can be inlined. And together with the use of [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) and some helper functions, it can be rewritten like so:

```
class Snoop {
public:
    …
    void log(LogLevel level, …) {
        if (level <= maximum_level)
            log_internal(level, …);
    }

    void Fatal(…) { log(LogLevel::FATAL, …); }
    …
private:
    …
    std::ofstream file;
    void log_internal(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message);
};

static void log_formatted(bool enabled, std::ofstream& file, LogLevel level, const std::string& formatted_message) {
    if (enabled) {
        file << formatted_message << '\n';
        if (LogLevel::FATAL || level == LogLevel::ERROR) {
            file.flush();
        }
    }
}

void Snoop::log_internal(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    std::string outstring = formatMessage(level, file, line, message);
    std::lock_guard lock(mutex);
    log_formatted(log_to_console, clog, level, outstring);
    log_formatted(log_to_file, file, level, outstring);
}

std::string Snoop::formatMessage(LogLevel level, const char* file, int line, const std::string& message) {
    if (log_formatter) {
        return log_formatter(level, file, line, message);
    }
    …
}
```

## The macros can be avoided in C++20

C++20 added [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), which gives you the filename and line number in a way that avoids having to use macros.